# Create a table from a hierarchy

Tags: r

I have a hierarchy and I'd like to create a table which captures the last value, the value before and the column number.

I've got no idea where to start.  I can calculate the column number as a new column, and then I think I need to melt the data but I can't work out on what variable and I don't know what to search for.

My input looks like this:

```
input = structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "ASIA PACIFIC", class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "AUSTRALIA", class = "factor"), 
    V3 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ACT", 
    "NEW SOUTH WALES"), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(1L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("CANBERRA", 
    "NEWCASTLE", "SYDNEY", "WOLLONGONG"), class = "factor"), 
    V5 = structure(c(9L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 10L, 1L), .Label = c("###", 
    "BONDI", "CAMPBELLTOWN", "GEORGE ST", "MAIN ST", "NEWTOWN", 
    "PITT ST", "POKOLBIN", "SMITH ST", "STRANGE PDE"), class = "factor"), 
    V6 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("###", 
    "CHARLES AVE", "FRANCIS ST", "TOM ST", "TONY LANE"), class = "factor"), 
    V7 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "###", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

And I'm looking to create the following output:

```
output = 
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(10L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 14L, 6L, 
13L, 11L, 15L, 2L, 12L, 8L, 7L, 1L), .Label = c("AUSTRALIA", 
"CANBERRA", "CHARLES AVE", "FRANCIS ST", "GEORGE ST", "MAIN ST", 
"NEW SOUTH WALES", "NEWCASTLE", "PITT ST", "SMITH ST", "STRANGE PDE", 
"SYDNEY", "TOM ST", "TONY LANE", "WOLLONGONG"), class = "factor"), 
    V2 = structure(c(6L, 4L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 5L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 
    1L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("ACT", "ASIA PACIFIC", "AUSTRALIA", 
    "BONDI", "CAMPBELLTOWN", "CANBERRA", "NEW SOUTH WALES", "NEWCASTLE", 
    "NEWTOWN", "POKOLBIN", "SYDNEY"), class = "factor"), V3 = c(5L, 
    6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

I haven't got a clue what I should search for to get started.  If anyone can suggest where I'd start, I'd be really grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually such missing values is represented by `NA` but here it is represented by `###`, we can remove those from every row and select last two values using `tail` and return the `length(new_x)`.

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(input, 1, function(x) 
       {new_x = x[x != "###"]; c(rev(tail(new_x, 2)), length(new_x)) })))

#           V1              V2 V3
#1 CHARLES AVE           BONDI  6
#2  FRANCIS ST         NEWTOWN  6
#3   GEORGE ST          SYDNEY  5
#4     PITT ST          SYDNEY  5
#5   TONY LANE    CAMPBELLTOWN  6
#6     MAIN ST       NEWCASTLE  5
#7      TOM ST        POKOLBIN  6
#8 STRANGE PDE       NEWCASTLE  5
#9  WOLLONGONG NEW SOUTH WALES  4
```

---

A `tidyverse` approach for the same could be

```
library(tidyverse)

input %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  gather(col, value, -row) %>%
  filter(value != "###") %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  mutate(last_value = row_number()) %>%
  slice(c(n(), n() - 1)) %>%
  mutate(col = c("col1", "col2"), 
        last_value = max(last_value)) %>%
  spread(col, value) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-row)

# A tibble: 9 x 3
#  last_value col1        col2           
#       <int> <chr>       <chr>          
#1          6 CHARLES AVE BONDI          
#2          6 FRANCIS ST  NEWTOWN        
#3          5 GEORGE ST   SYDNEY         
#4          5 PITT ST     SYDNEY         
#5          6 TONY LANE   CAMPBELLTOWN   
#6          5 MAIN ST     NEWCASTLE      
#7          6 TOM ST      POKOLBIN       
#8          5 STRANGE PDE NEWCASTLE      
#9          4 WOLLONGONG  NEW SOUTH WALES
```

Comment: thanks. i don't think I follow the example, if i wanted to extend it all the way to the top (I've edit the output because i can't post it here), how do I avoid the duplicates?

Comment: @nicshah how is the first value? `SMITH ST,  CANBERRA` which is the column name of the dataframe? Why the last two values of the columns is not selected?

Comment: Sorry @RonakShah - I've stuffed up and forgotten to adder "header = F" on my input.

Comment: @nicshah If you want to avoid the duplicates then why do you have some values like "NEW SOUTH WALES " , "AUSTRALIA ", "SYDNEY" repeated in your output ?